# Angular material MdMenu doesn't work

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I have code from Angular material doc:

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
    <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>
```

And have error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with
>   "exportAs" set to "mdMenu"

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.11",
"@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
}
```

How fix it?

Comment: try upgrading all your dependencies, and angular version to latest

Comment: If you have the latest version of material, Md has to be replace by Mat.

Comment: you need to update your angular version to the latest beta - it should work then

Comment: @AlexWoe89 . Can I downgrade the version of the @angular/material without updating all Angular dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hareesh @Wanderille @AlexWoe89 Thanks for answers, i found solution is so easy :)

Remove "mdMenu" from md-menu

In summary:

```
  <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <md-menu #menu>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </md-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<mat-menu>` instead of `<md-menu>` and import 'MatMenuModule' instead of 'MdMenuModule' and it should work fine.